# Check TO See If All Items From 1 List Are In Another List

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have 2 Lists

- The first one has 2 properties ItemA and ItemB
- The second one has 2 properties ProductA and ProductB

In my first list I have populated

```
ItemA=20, ItemB=30
ItemA=40, ItemB=50
ItemA=60, ItemB=80
```

I am looking for a way to check a list of Product that it contains all of the items in
the list of Items (order doesnt matter, extras doesnt matter) i.e.

- would return **true**

  ```
  ProductA=40, ProductB=50
  ProductA=20, ProductB=30
  ProductA=60, ProductB=80
  ProductA=1000, ProductB=2000
  ```
- would return **false** and print `ItemA=40`, `ItemB=50` since `ItemA=40`, `ItemB=50` is missing

  ```
  ProductA=20, ProductB=30
  ProductA=60, ProductB=80
  ProductA=1000, ProductB=2000
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to combine the `All` and the `Any` linq methods (sorry for the C#)

```
var items = new[]
    {
        new {ItemA = 20, ItemB = 30},
        new {ItemA = 40, ItemB = 50},
        new {ItemA = 60, ItemB = 80},
    };
var products1 = new[]
    {
        new {ProductA = 40, ProductB = 50},
        new {ProductA = 20, ProductB = 30},
        new {ProductA = 60, ProductB = 80},
        new {ProductA = 1000, ProductB = 2000},
    };
var products2 = new[]
    {
        new {ProductA = 20, ProductB = 30},
        new {ProductA = 60, ProductB = 80},
        new {ProductA = 1000, ProductB = 2000}
    };

items.All(i => products1
            .Any(p => p.ProductA == i.ItemA && p.ProductB == i.ItemB)); // true
items.All(i => products2
            .Any(p => p.ProductA == i.ItemA && p.ProductB == i.ItemB)); // false
```

For all of your `items` there should be at least on item from the `products` exits which has the matching properties.

If you also what to collect the missing items you can also do it in the `All` predicate:

```
var missing = new List<object>();
items.All(i =>
    {
        if (products1.Any(p => p.ProductA == i.ItemA && p.ProductB == i.ItemB))
            return true;
        //no matching item has found so add it to the missing "list"
        missing.Add(i);
        return false;
    });
```

However if you are starting to modify state in your LINQ methods then they are probably not the best solution so you are better to have two nested `foreach` and to the checking inside them.

Comment: can this also print out the missing items

Comment: In the `All` fuction predicate you can have any complex function so you can also collect there the missing items. But if your use case is that complex you are probably better to have two nested `foreach` and inside them check for the matchin/missing entries

Comment: can you show the nested foreach solution if thats better?

Answer (score 0):

Define two [Dictionaries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1), one for `ItemA` and one for `ItemB`, which use the number after the **=** sign as keys and bools for values. After that, start going through your second list and whenever you see a a number for `ProductA` or `ProductB`, mark its corresponding key in the corresponding dictionary to **true**. After that, go through both dictionaries, and if there is a **false** key, then all items form the first list **are not** contained in the second list. Short example:

We have

```
ItemA=20, ItemB=30
ItemA=40, ItemB=50
```

And now we define our 2 dictionaries. Now we have `DictionaryA` with

```
[20]-false
[40]-false
```

and `DictionaryB` with:

```
[30]-false
[50]-false
```

Now lets take

```
ProductA=40, ProductB=50
ProductA=20, ProductB=30
ProductA=60, ProductB=80
ProductA=1000, ProductB=2000
```

As we go throu all `ProductA`s and `ProductB`s, our Dictionaries now look like this:

```
DictionaryA     DictionaryB
[20]-true      [30]-true
[40]-true      [50]-true
```

since all keys are marked **true**, then the first list is contained in the second.

---

Now lets take

```
ProductA=20, ProductB=30
ProductA=60, ProductB=80
ProductA=1000, ProductB=2000
```

As we go throu all `ProductA`s and `ProductB`s, our Dictionaries now look like this:

```
DictionaryA     DictionaryB
[20]-true       [30]-true
[40]-false      [50]-false
```

since there are keys that are marked **false**, then the first list is **not** contained in the second.

---

Another good(and better) solution is to use a Hashset and instead of using a bool value, just to remove the key. After that if the set is not empty, then the first list is **not** contained in the second.

Comment: Is there a simpler linq solution maybe?

Comment: There is, but I'd argue how good it is performance-wise -> http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fe92c3c0-658d-453b-abce-3fce8a670e7a/check-if-an-array-is-in-another-bigger-array-using-linq?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: Actually just look at @nemesv answer